# expected class-name before ‘{’ token error

Tags: c++, class, sfml, legacy

I'm working on SFML here and I want to create my own RenderWindow class with Legacy. But the g++ prints this **error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token** at line 7 in .hpp

I all ready ask Google about it but I didn't find what I was expecting at so I hope you will be able to help me to find this out :)

#### my_render_window.hpp

```
#ifndef MY_RENDER_WINDOW_HPP_
# define MY_RENDER_WINDOW_HPP_

# include <SFML/Window.hpp>

class MyRenderWindow : public sf::RenderWindow
{
public:
  MyRenderWindow();

protected:

};

#endif /* !MY_RENDER_WINDOW_HPP_ */
```

#### my_render_window.cpp

```
#include "my_render_window.hpp"

MyRenderWindow::MyRenderWindow(): sf::RenderWindow()
{

}
```

I compile correctly without these files and taking base `sf::RenderWindow` class to run with.

Comment: What is the failing line number?

Comment: I edit right now, thanks it is line 7 in hpp for you know

Comment: Apparently the linker can't find sf::RenderWindow.

Comment: @Lundin: The linker has nothing to do with this.

Comment: The documentation says to include `RenderWindow.hpp` for `sf::RenderWindow`.

Comment: So weird, I compile correctly with with sfml and when I use sf::RenderWindow in my main there is no problems here. And in my main there is the same include instruction

Comment: @chris, ah, sorry, I failed to see it was a constructor. My bad.

Comment: @chris Window.hpp include RenderWindow.hpp itself, it's like a big include file.

Comment: @RodolpheChartier, It doesn't seem that way from [this](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/Window_8hpp_source.php) or [this](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/Window_8hpp_source.php). The `Window/Window.hpp` they include doesn't seem to either. Of course I kind of just reasoned that the other included headers looked unlikely to.

Comment: @chris I try to only include Window.hpp, and got the same errors... :(

Comment: @RodolpheChartier: Does it work if you include `RenderWindow.hpp`? The [documentation](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php) certainly says you need that header, not `Window.hpp` (which as far as I can see doesn't include `RenderWindow.hpp`).

Comment: @chris Yes I tried this but it cannot find the file and I tried a lot of possibilities for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I dont know why but with this include `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` just after the `#include <SFML/Window.hpp>` it works !

So weird... :(
`#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` may includes a file that I need to.

Comment: Looks like `Graphics.hpp` includes `Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp`, which corresponds to the listed general `RenderWindow.hpp` they have. I find that a little bit confusing, but ok.

Comment: RenderWindow is part of SFML/Graphic not SFML/Window so my bad... :S I just find this reading the Window and Graphics header files...